# Changing Tkinter Screen when button is clicked?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am aiming to change the a part of the Tkinter screen when a button is clicked.  Do I have to destroy the screen then redraw it (to create the illusion that only a part is being changed?) Or can I keep the button there and somehow only change one part (like the graphics.) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not have to destroy the screen and redraw it. You can easily insert widgets into the current window when a button is clicked. There's nothing special about being run from a button click -- the code is the same as your initialization code.

Comment: So would one button have a function that basically creates another button on the screen?